# TypeScript how to type hint a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I would like to type hint my function in TypeScript as below:

```js
// would like to remove this type
type FN<TArgs, TReturn> = (args: TArgs) => TReturn;

interface Args {
  itemWeight: number;
  quantity: number;
}

const calcTotalWeight: FN<Args, number> = ({ itemWeight, quantity }) => itemWeight * quantity;
```

Is there any built-in generic that provides this utility? Currently, I have created one as above, but I feel as if this could be a very common use case. For example, react has `FC`.

I do note that this type requires your function to be unary, but that's the whole point here. It's common to have a unary function, with the single argument an object so that we can have "named" parameters.

Does anyone know if this exists, or thoughts on whether this is a good idea?

## Extension:

Does anyone know how to make the second argument of the generic optional so that it is inferred if not provided? For example:

```js
const calcTotalWeight: FN<Args> = ({ itemWeight, quantity }) => itemWeight * quantity;

// typeof calcTotalWeight === FN<Args, number> , or
// typeof calcTotalWeight === (Args) => number
```

Comment: check it out this utils function in typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: @MohitSharma which one?

Comment: I don't understand why you need `FN` at all.  If you don't annotate the variable but instead annotate the function parameter, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Na2RPm), does that work for you?  If so, I could write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: The `FN` type not only exists in typescript, it has its own special syntax. This is exactly what the `(args: Args) => number` function type syntax does, and making an `FN` type here only makes that more cryptic, IMHO. I'm not sure the problem you are trying to solve here is actually a problem.

Comment: @thecartesianman @DaveMeehan use `ReturnType`